# How to use variable to re-fetch the querie again?

Tags: typescript, graphql, vuejs3, apollo

I'm new at Vue and Graphql and I'm trying to understand how to re-fetch the queries after typing a new value in the input.

I'm trying through props, to change the value of the variable responsible("searchQuerie") for the queries.

But I'm not understanding how to change the value through the input field.

Can someone help me?

```
<template>
  <div class="app">
    <input type="text" :value="id" @input="changeMessage" />
    <div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>

    <div v-else-if="error">Error: {{ error.message }}</div>

    <ul v-else-if="result && result.popularTitles">
      <li v-for="(item, index) in result.popularTitles" :key="index">
        {{ item }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { useQuery } from "@vue/apollo-composable";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  props: ["id"],

  setup(props) {

    const { result, loading, error, refetch } = useQuery(
      gql`
        query GetSuggestedTitles(
          $country: Country!
          $language: Language!
          $first: Int!
          $filter: TitleFilter
        ) {
          popularTitles(country: $country, first: $first, filter: $filter) {
            edges {
              node {
                ...SuggestedTitle
                __typename
              }
              __typename
            }
            __typename
          }
        }

        fragment SuggestedTitle on MovieOrShow {
          id
          objectType
          objectId
          content(country: $country, language: $language) {
            fullPath
            title
            originalReleaseYear
            posterUrl
            fullPath
            __typename
          }
          __typename
        }
      `,
      () => ({
        country: "DE" as string,
        language: "de" as string,
        first: 4 as number,
        filter: { searchQuery: props.id },
      })
    );
    
    console.log(result);

    return {
      result,
      loading,
      error,
      refetch,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeMessage(event: any) {
      this.result = event.target.value;
      this.$emit("messageChanged", this.result);
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already destructuring the result and also returning `refetch`, which according to the docs, you can simply call as a method when needed.

Edit: if you need to change the term and fetch again with a different input, you could wrap your code that fetches data in a function, let's call it something like `fetchData()` that returns result, error and more if needed.
In your `setup()` function, after declaring `fetchData()`, call it so the data get's fetched on page load.
When the user digits something, handle the input and simply call `fetchData()` again.

I'm trying on a local project, and this works for me:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="maxResults" type="text" placeholder="number of results" @change="fetchData()">
    <pre>{{ output }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  const maxResults = ref(2); // example dynamic value: max 2 results by default
  const output = ref([]);

  const fetchData = () => {
    const { result, error } = useQuery(gql`
      query GetSuggestedTitles {
        ... (limit: ${maxResults.value}) {
          ...
        }
      }`
    );

    if (error.value !== null) {
      console.error("error fetching data:", error.value);
    } else {
      output.value = result.value;
    }
  };

  fetchData(); // here you call it on page load
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Nicola! Thanks for the reply. 
Yes, but how can I change the value of searchQuery when recalling?

Comment: You need to fetch content on page load and also when the input value changes? Or just when the user digits something in the input, so not on page load?

Comment: Yes exactly, I need to fetch content on page load, not necessary when the input value changes.
I just want to be able to write something else in the input and afterward, it fetches.

Comment: I edited my answer, try it now

Comment: For a better understanding. This query is from a search input API. 
So it is already retrieving some value. 
I want now to be able to interact with this querie changing the value of the searchQuerie as I want to have different results from the API

Comment: Thank you very much for the updated answer, Nicola! I'll give it a try and then I come back with the answer

Comment: unfortunately I'm still not being able to fix it.

Comment: Added a small example, I tried on a project of mine and this works, hope this points you in the right direction at least

Comment: Thank you so much, Nicola! But somehow I'm still not able to achieve the supposed action! I guess that my lack of experience with Vue doesn't help much :)